# listview layout

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am trying to create a small photo album layout in vb.net using a `listview` that when a new album has been created it shows it in the `listview` as a 3 x 2 grid. But when it gets more than a 3 x 2, I want it to just show a link listing all albums. Here is a image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you dont ask a specific question, you are just going to get downvoted and your question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

just check the listview items count if its count more than 6 then a button or hyperlink "...All albums" shows on page otherwise this button or hyperlink hides on page....